# Finding and displaying image src attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a problem and an try to find  in one  week. I need help :(

I have a script work with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list_images = 'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';
var images = list_images.split('|');
</script>
```

but know in blogger always give more tab in my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list_images = '

<div></div>
<a herf="anything"><img src="image1.jpg"><a/>
<a herf="anything"><img src="image2.jpg"><a/>
<a herf="anything"><img src="image3.jpg"><a/>
<a herf="anything"><img src="image4.jpg"><a/>
<a herf="anything"><img src="image5.jpg"><a/>
<li><img src="image6.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image7.jpg"></li>
<br/>

';
var images = list_images.split('|');
</script>
```

**I want remove all tabd and convernt them like**

```
var list_images = 'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';
```

Comment: First of all change `herf` into `href`

Comment: You cannot span multiple lines in a JavaScript string.

Comment: Hi powtac , I dont know anything about java and more. Just know a litte litte think css , and my english language bad too. Sorrry about mistake herf and href . U can see 2 link of me to view my problem. I dont know how to  talk about it more :(

Comment: Hi pimvdb. The problem of me is : How to search and replace to remove all and give the correct script :

Comment: @MIF: Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @pimvdb : This is jquery code i found in internet. U can see 2 link of me :( .  .. I see one code can do it but i do'nt know how to use.... 'var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    files.push(imgs[i].src);
}
alert(files.join('|'));
'

Comment: This is the 3rd time you have asked the same question. The two previous questions have 3 answers between them that might be able to help you. Your profile (http://stackoverflow.com/users/640943/mif) shows the 3 questions.

Comment: Sorry andyb , this is a first time i post to ask about code. I will do'nt do it again. I try to fix but i dont know anything about javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding and displaying image src attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166772/finding-and-displaying-image-src-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

The Blogger editor is unfortunately not designed well to handle code blocks.

By default, it adds a `<br/>` tag to the end of every line causing your well formatted script to fail.

The only workaround I've seen so far isn't pretty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*
  */var list_images = /*
  */'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';/*
  */var images = list_images.split('|');/*
*/</script>
```

Essentially everything after then end of a line up to the begining of the next line is forced to be a comment so that when Blogger injects the `<br/>` tags they are ignored by the browser.

Result after Blogger injects the BRs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*<br/>
  */var list_images = /*<br/>
  */'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';/*<br/>
  */var images = list_images.split('|');/*<br/>
*/</script><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks you, but the problem of me is ----- > var list_images = 'have a block of html and only want get scr link and replace with the |'.

Comment: oh, ok... and you can't just edit the variable to only include the src attributes? (e.g. if you are injecting this HTML elsewhere, it would likely be easier to build it in JavaScript from the list of src images)

Comment: If you are stuck with the HTML fragment, then you could do a split by `src="` then loop over the results (ignore the first result) and trim off anything after (and including) the `"` quote character.

Comment: Yes, i cant edit the variable because i have more old data :(. When i change the way to load image i have problem with old data

Comment: I added a separate answer based on the comments.

Comment: You give me a best idea. Can u help me to trim  by jquery ? . I so stupid :(

Comment: http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/02/blog-post.html . Can u view this link to see html code :(. May be i so stupid and dont know use it

Comment: THANK to all . I very very thanks about your help . My problem is sloved. Love Stack over flow somuch :X

Answer (score 1):

Just split the text differently:

```
var list_images = '...blah blah...';

var firstPass = list_images.split('src="');

var entry;
//skip first result
for(var i=1;i<firstPass.length;i++){
  entry = firstPass[i];
  firstPass[i] = entry.substr(0,entry.indexOf('"'));
}

//firstPass (you can change the name) now contains the list of src's
```

Comment: http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/02/blog-post.html. Can u view this link to see html code :(. May be i so stupid and dont know use it . I will try but not working

Comment: scunliffe Can u help me if u see my comment. I very thanks your help .

Comment: on the site the code got cut off... the closing bracket of the for loop "`}`" is not there... or anything after it... e.g. I'm not sure what you want to do with it once you have the array?

Comment: http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/03/httpcomic.html -- > WORKed with old code       . http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/02/blog-post.html --> my problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this HTML is in the DOM, you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src_array = [];

    $('img').each(function() {
        src_array.push(this.src);
    });

    var joined_src = src_array.join('|');
});
</script>

<div></div>
<a href="anything"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
<a href="anything"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
<a href="anything"><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
<a href="anything"><img src="image4.jpg"></a>
<a href="anything"><img src="image5.jpg"></a>
<li><img src="image6.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image7.jpg"></li>
<br/>
```

If it isn't part of the DOM, you could replace the `.each()` code with:

```
$(some_html_string).find('img').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hans/SfNCF/

Comment: thanks hansengel , i will try to use it in my code. Hope i can do it

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate elements within your document with Javascript I'd strongly suggest using some sort of framework such as Jquery, which will easily allow you find and manipulate images without hassle, the code would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //find stuff
  $('img').each(function(){ 

      //do stuff with it
      $(this).attr('[name of the attribute]','[value you want to put in it]');

  });

});
```

If you are new to Javascript or haven't used Jquery here is a good place to start: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

```
//this is your list (this variable will hold your html)
var list_images;

//this varaible will hold array of images
var newList=[]

$(list_images).find('img').each(function(){
      newList.push($(this).attr('src'));
});

//your list is ready acess your variable 'newList'
//this variable hold an array in format
//['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'];

//the string
var stringList=newList.join('|');

//this will hold a string in format 
// "image1.jpg|image2.jpg}image3.jpg"
```