# Finding and displaying image src attributes

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a problem and an try to find  in one  week. I need help :(

I have a script work with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list_images = 'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';
var images = list_images.split('|');
</script>
```

but know in blogger always give more tab in my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list_images = '

<div></div>
<a href="anything"><img src="image1.jpg"><a/>
<a href="anything"><img src="image2.jpg"><a/>
<a href="anything"><img src="image3.jpg"><a/>
<a href="anything"><img src="image4.jpg"><a/>
<a href="anything"><img src="image5.jpg"><a/>
<li><img src="image6.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image7.jpg"></li>
<br/>

';
var images = list_images.split('|');
</script>
```

**I want remove all tabs and convert them like**

```
var list_images = 'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';
```

[Finding and displaying image src attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166772/finding-and-displaying-image-src-attributes) -> Old question

http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/03/httpcomic.html  - > Work good

http://manhualayout.blogspot.com/2011/02/blog-post.html  -> My  problem make my crazy in one week :(

I Can't just edit the variable of the block HTML ...I want find a way to search and replace to remove all and got the link with the |

Please help me . Very very thanks .. Me so stupid :(